# How I move these files based on their names in R or terminal

Tags: r, bash, looper

> EDITED

I have list of my samples in first column and corresponding file name for my .vcf files in second column of a file name `clin_name.txt` like below. For example name of one vcf is `LP6008031-DNA_A04_vs_LP6008032-DNA_D03.snp.pass.vcf`

```
OC/AH/120/E/T3  LP6005409-DNA_F01
OC/AH/126/E/T1  LP2000325-DNA_A01
OC/AH/136/E/T3  LP6005409-DNA_E02
```

This is the link of my file https://www.dropbox.com/s/mvzf47feiqe7x69/clin_name.txt.txt?dl=0

In the second file name `pre_post.list` I have information of pre or post treatment for each sample like this

```
pre-treated post-treated
OC/AH/120   OC/AH/065
OC/AH/126   OC/AH/069
OC/AH/136   OC/AH/074
OC/AH/160   OC/AH/084
```

This is link of this https://www.dropbox.com/s/ikrl1h8yoc0sngx/pre_post.list.xlsx?dl=0

As you suggested I typed

```
cat pre_post.list | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's@.*/@@'  > post_list.txt
cat pre_post.list | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's@.*/@@'  > pre_list.txt
```

Then I have

```
pre-treated
120
126
136
160
182

post-treated
065
069
074
084
```

in I typed `./test.sh` in which I wrote

```
for item in  $(cat  pre_list.txt | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,4}');
    do if grep -q $item clin_name.txt ;
    then out=$(grep $item clin_name.txt | awk  '{print $1}');
         cp *$out* /temp/hgig/fi1d18/TRG45/snp/
    else echo post_list $item;  fi;  done;
```

That returns

```
cp: cannot stat `*OC/AH/069/S/T3*': No such file or directory
[fi1d18@cyan01 snp]$
```

Or I run

```
for item in  $(cat  post_list.txt | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,4}');
    do if grep -q $item clin_name.txt ;
    then out=$(grep $item clin_name.txt | awk  '{print $1}');
         cp *$out* /temp/hgig/fi1d18/TRG45/snp/pre/
    else cp *$out* /temp/hgig/fi1d18/TRG45/snp/post/;  fi;  done;
```

That returns

```
cp: cannot stat `OC/ST/026/S/T1*': No such file or directory
[fi1d18@cyan01 snp]$
```

I really don't know how to solve this :(

Comment: This is more of a job for snakemake or similar. You'd end up following the same logic in R if you really prefer that. Show us what you've tried so far, since there's no reason someone should write a custom program for you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the names of all the files from one group are in file named list.

```
cat pre_post.list | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's@.*/@@'  > post_list.txt
cat pre_post.list | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's@.*/@@'  > pre_list.txt
```

Now you have two number list

```
    for item in  $(cat  pre_list.txt | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,4}');
    do if grep -q $item clin_name.txt ;
    then out=$(grep $item clin_name.txt | awk  '{print $1}');
         cp *$out* /dir/for_pre_files/
    else echo post_list $item;  fi;  done
```

for post

```
    for item in  $(cat  post_list.txt | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,4}');
    do if grep -q $item clin_name.txt ;
    then out=$(grep $item clin_name.txt | awk  '{print $1}');
         cp *$out* /dir/for_post_file/
    else echo Prelist $item;  fi;  done
```

or you could do this if one that isn't in post belongs in pre

```
    for item in  $(cat  post_list.txt | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,4}');
    do if grep -q $item clin_name.txt ;
    then out=$(grep $item clin_name.txt | awk  '{print $1}');
         cp *$out* /dir/for_post_file/
    else cp *$out* /dir/for_pre_file/;  fi;  done
```

Comment: Sorry I tried your kindly code but did not work and I got this error in very  early stage  [fi1d18@cyan01 ~]$ cat pre_post.list | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's@.*/@@'  > post_list.txt
cat: pre_post.list: No such file or directory

Comment: You have to change the names in my bash code to reflect the names of the actual files on my computer

Comment: Thank you I am getting this the for loop  grep: clin_name.txt: No such file or directory
post_list 069 this being repeated for all of samples

Comment: You need to replace all the file names in the script with your file names.

Comment: Sorry what is "clin_name.txt" here? I mean where clin_name.txt comes from?  If I know what clin_name.txt is, I might be able to adopt that to my case Thank you

Comment: file that contains all OC/AH/120/E/T3  LP6005409-DNA_F01
OC/AH/126/E/T1  LP2000325-DNA_A01
OC/AH/136/E/T3  LP6005409-DNA_E02

Comment: Hello @Michael Hearn I tried what you kindly wrote for me edited in my main post but I am getting errors like cp: missing destination file operand after `/temp/hgig/fi1d18/TRG45/snp/pre/'